# WSL2が突然起動しなくなりました

Tags: windows, wsl-2

Powershellからwslを起動したところ、突如以下の表示がでました。

```
Windows の仮想マシン プラットフォーム機能を有効にして、BIOS で仮想化が有効になっていることを確認してください。
詳細については、https://aka.ms/wsl2-install を参照してください

[プロセスはコード 4294967295 で終了しました]
```

しかし、仮想マシンプラットフォーム機能もBIOSの仮想化も有効化されている状態です。
何度か再起動を繰り返したりしましたが、何も変わりませんでした。
最悪wslを再インストールすることになるのかもしれませんが、いくつかファイルがUbuntuのホームディレクトリに置いてあり取り出せない状況なので、出来る限り修復したいと考えています。

原因が分かる方はよろしくお願いします。

OS: Windows10 バージョン2004(OS build 19041.904)
wsl distribution :

```
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu          Stopped         2
  Ubuntu-18.04    Stopped         2
```

Comment: WSLはwindowsに仮想環境を作成するだけなのでファイルはエクスプローラから参照できます

Comment: Windows側から、Ubuntuのホームディレクトリを何故か参照出来ないんですよ。AppData以下のrootfsディレクトリが存在しなくて、どこにあるかわからないんですよね。\\wsl$も今現状は存在しないことになってますし..

Comment: 参考までに、WSL/WSL2 の issue を眺めてみると、最近(過去1~2年) Windows Update 直後に WSL が起動しなくなるという事象が散見されます。

Comment: エラーメッセージでgoogle検索すると、関連しそうな事例と対策が出てきます。